# Dynamic array with VBA - Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, formula

I m using VBA code to import below formula to specific cell:

`.Range("AA9").Formula = "=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(tblClients[Clients],ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$2,tblClients[Clients])),""Not Found"")))"`

What i get when formula imported via VBA is:

`=@SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(tblClients[Clients],ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$2,tblClients[Clients])),"Not Found")))`

and only the first option of the array appears. As soon as i remove the `@` from the formula the whole array appears. So i have two questions:

1. Why `@` imported and how to remove it?
2. Why i can not import the same formula in the cell below?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Set the formula using .Formula2

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks a lot for your answer. I want to import a dynamic array in column AA which it will filter by the value in column C. Each row (approximately 30 rows) one under the other will include this array. Is it possible? Or i will get splill erro?

Comment: You can’t add a second array formula directly under a previous one if the spill ranges might overlap

Comment: @TimWilliams do you have any ideas on how to solve this? To create multiple arrays? (One array for each line)

Comment: What would the second formula look like?

Comment: All formulas, for all line will be the same. The only issue is that i can not import multiple dynamic formulas one over the other due to overlap. This is the main issue and i m trying to overcome it. That s way i m asking for any possible solution

Comment: Exactly the same?

Comment: Yes, the dynamic array will pointing a table column. In each row, the user will type a prefix in a cell and the dynamic array will be filtered by the specific prefix and a data validation list will shows only the filtered values from the dynamic array. Having in mind that each row will have a different prefix i think i have to create multiple arrays. What is your opinion?

Comment: Where does the data validation list appear?

Comment: I have something for you to try but your question is closed, so I can't post an answer.  If you post a new question I will answer there.

Comment: @TimWilliams https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77838547/import-multiple-dynamic-arrays-with-formulas-excel